# Lost my windows 7 after installing ubuntu

Tags: windows-7

So i just installed Ubuntu latest version and i can't find my windows 7 anywhere.While doing the install i chose the "install Ubuntu along with windows7" but nowhere to find them after that.Please help me.

Comment: Hello Nope, we'll need a bit more information in order to help. When you switch on your computer does it load up Ubuntu? If it does, click the top left icon on the launcher and type in 'Disks'. You should see a program called Disks and when you launch that it should tell you a bit of information about the partitions on your Hard Disk. This should let you see if there is still a partition on your disk with Windows 7 still on it. If it's still there then you we can look into how to fix that.

Comment: Can you paste to your post the output that you get when your run `lsblk -fs`

Comment: Are you selecting the correct boot option? Usually F12 or delete at the BIOS screen and select windows